# Selecting element inside of a jQuery each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am looping through a specific element and storing values from each element using jQuery .each() function. I am successful in pulling two values, but after that, I am getting undefined errors and have been stuck on this.

The element I am looping through is "pod-listing", so I use this...

```js
$(".pod-listing").each(function (i, obj) {
  alert($(this).find('div a').attr('title'));
  alert($(this).find('div a').attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pod-listing">
  <div class="pod-listing-header">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/inward/record.uri?partnerID=890sj&amp;scp=7889706&amp;origin=inward"
       title="Guidelines on the use of current (rJKD)">
      </a>
    <div class="article-info">Volume 128, Issue 1, January 2017</div>
  </div>
  <small>
    Bob Smith | Sally Sue | John Jones  
  </small>
</div>
```

And this works successfully. However, when I try to get the text inside the "article-info" div and the text inside the  tag, I am unsuccessful. I have tried every combination I can think of to get these values. Using this current syntax of looping through my "pod-listing" divs (there are multiple of these on the page, this is just the first one in the example), how can I get the values of the "article-info" class and the  element?

Comment: "I have tried every combination I can think of to get these values. " please show what you have tried

Comment: "when I try to get the text inside the "article-info" div and the text inside the tag, I am unsuccessful." what did you try and what error did you get? And what "tag" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Get `article-info` div text:**

```
$(".pod-listing").each(function(i, obj) {
   alert($(this).find('div .article-info').text());
});
```

**Get `small` tag text:**

```
$(".pod-listing").each(function(i, obj) {
   alert($(this).find('small').text());
});
```

**DEMO:**

```js
$(".pod-listing").each(function(i, obj) {
  console.log($(this).find('div .article-info').text());
  console.log($(this).find('small').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pod-listing">
  <div class="pod-listing-header">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/inward/record.uri?partnerID=890sj&amp;scp=7889706&amp;origin=inward" title="Guidelines on the use of current (rJKD)">
    </a>
    <div class="article-info">Volume 128, Issue 1, January 2017</div>
  </div>
  <small>Bob Smith | Sally Sue | John Jones</small>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply target the element with class and (or tagName) and use [**`.text()`**](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
var articleInfo = $(this).find('div.article-info').text();
var smallInfo = $(this).find('small').text();
```

```js
$(".pod-listing").each(function(i, obj){
   console.log($(this).find('div.article-info').text());
   console.log($(this).find('small').text().trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pod-listing">
  <div class="pod-listing-header">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/inward/record.uri?partnerID=890sj&amp;scp=7889706&amp;origin=inward" title="Guidelines on the use of current (rJKD)"></a>
    <div class="article-info">Volume 128, Issue 1, January 2017</div>
  </div>
  <small>
    Bob Smith | Sally Sue | John Jones  
  </small>
</div>
```

Comment: @codewelldesign, please see the executable code snippet in the updated answer:)

Comment: @codewelldesign, what is the reason behind not working your code as it is working here?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.html()`:

```js
$(".pod-listing").each(function(i, obj){
  alert($(this).find('div a').attr('title'));
  alert($(this).find('div a').attr('href'));
  alert($(this).find('.article-info').html());
  alert($(this).find('small').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pod-listing">
  <div class="pod-listing-header">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/inward/record.uri?partnerID=890sj&amp;scp=7889706&amp;origin=inward" title="Guidelines on the use of current (rJKD)">
    </a>
    <div class="article-info">Volume 128, Issue 1, January 2017</div>
  </div>
  <small>
    Bob Smith | Sally Sue | John Jones  
  </small>
</div>
```